# Agregar un objecto a un campo de un DataTable c#

Tags: c#, asp, datatable

Tengo el siguiente `datatable` con un `DataRow`

```
DataTable InfoHDVIndicador = new DataTable();
DataRow vlrInd = InfoHDVIndicador.NewRow();
```

con 18 columnas, una de ellas es :

```
 /*18*/ InfoHDVIndicador.Columns.Add("FuentesArray");
```

me ha funcionado para crear un datatable de Strings sin problema, sin embargo quiero enviar un objeto en la #18 :

```
List<fuentesIndicador> fuente = new List<fuentesIndicador>();            

  fuentesIndicador fuentetemp = new fuentesIndicador() {
                        numeroCedula = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                        nombre       = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                        operacion    = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString(),
                        campanas     = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString(),
                    };

 fuente.Add(fuentetemp);
```

lo agrego al dataRow

```
      vlrInd["FuentesArray"] = fuente;
```

y por último, agrego este dataRow al datatable:

```
 InfoHDVIndicador.Rows.Add(vlrInd);
```

Sin embargo me lo envía como un String Que vale lo siguiente:

```
"System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LogicBo.HojaVidaIndicadoresBo.HojaVidaIndicadoresBo+fuentesIndicador]"
```

necesito enviar el objeto para recuperarlo después, ¿cómo debo enviarlo o anexarlo al datatable?, gracias.

Comment: No es posible guardar eso dentro de un `datatable`. [Documentación](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn.datatype?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: gracias, rayos que horrible ahora si tengo problemas

Comment: Porque no creas una clase y guardas todo dentro de una clase?

Comment: No tiene mucho sentido guardar una coleccion en una columna de un DataTable... que quieres hacer?

Comment: es un desarrollo que ya está hecho así y no puedo editar mucho código u_u

Comment: Mejoralo, esa es la idea siempre mejorar el código no te amarres a eso tienes que ser creativo, intenta con una clase.

Comment: @Pikoh lo que pasa es que envio informacion sobre un "indicador" que a su vez tiene elementos que pueden tener N sub elementos

Comment: Si,eso lo entiendo, pero pq necesitas un DataTable? Para mostrarlo en un datagrid o para que?

Comment: Otra opción sería serializar la lista a xml y almacenar ese xml en la columna...pero sigo sin entender que ganarías con ello

Comment: pues es que el desarrollo retorna un dataset y luego lo guarda en una variable de sesion, lo pinta en una vista como un Modal y luego el usuario decide si aprobarlo o no, es complejo, y si lo cambio por una clase tocaría cambiar muchisimas cosas que no me alcanza para el tiempo que me dieron

Comment: Pues tratalo entonces como un json y recuperalo en json

Comment: si, estaba pensando en eso, muchas gracias

Comment: Exacto, lo que dice @VictorPerdomo es la mejor opción. Esa comunicación debe ser siempre serializando los datos, bien en xml, bien en json

Comment: si srs, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una column del datatable no sabe que es un objeto de la forma que lo estas asignando, este solo reconoce tipos simples como `string`, `int`, etc

Si quiere asignar un objeto deberias serializar a `xml` o `json`

```
List<fuentesIndicador> fuente = new List<fuentesIndicador>();            

fuentesIndicador fuentetemp = new fuentesIndicador() {
                    numeroCedula = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][0].ToString(),
                    nombre       = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][1].ToString(),
                    operacion    = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][4].ToString(),
                    campanas     = result.Tables[0].Rows[i][8].ToString(),
                };

fuente.Add(fuentetemp);


XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<fuentesIndicador>));  

string result = "";
using(StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, fuente);
    result = textWriter.ToString();
}

vlrInd["FuentesArray"] = result;
```

como observaras la lista se serializa a xml y luego ese string resultante lo asignas a la row, para recuperar el dato solo tendrias que deserializar

[Examples of XML Serialization](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/examples-of-xml-serialization)

Comment: Muchas gracias, si efectivamente debo seralizar a json o xml.